# filtering timestamps in dplyr across multiple years

Tags: r, datetime, filter, dplyr

I have this simple data set where time is formatted `as.POSIXct` (my data is much larger but this should work fine):

```
df <- tibble(
  "BirdsID" = c("1234", "1234", "1235", "1236",
                "1236", "1237", "1238", "1239"),
  "Sex" = c("M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F"),
  "Time" = as.POSIXct(c("2019-03-15", "2020-03-16", "2019-05-23", "2019-06-07", 
                        "2020-04-29", "2021-02-15", "2021-02-16", "2021-01-30"))
)
```

I'd like to filter the data into observations that are between February 1 and July 1 regardless of year. I've seen other posts that suggest using `between` inside of `dplyr::filter`; however, these data are across 3 years so there's technically three `filter(between(` arguments, one for each year. Is there a single line of code or function in dplyr that I'm missing? Perhaps adding a column for "spring" and subsetting from there? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggested `lubridate::month` function I have an answer which is below:

```
df <- tibble(
  "BirdsID" = c("1234", "1234", "1235", "1236",
                "1236", "1237", "1238", "1239"),
  "Sex" = c("M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F"),
  "Time" = as.POSIXct(c("2019-03-15", "2020-03-16", "2019-05-23", "2019-06-07", 
                        "2020-04-29", "2021-02-15", "2021-02-16", "2021-01-30"))
)

df %>% 
  mutate(Time2 = as.Date(Time)) %>%
  mutate(month = month(Time2)) %>%
  filter(between(month, 2, 7))
```

A bit clunky where I had to `mutate` twice but it works. I likely could combine the mutations into one line of code. Thanks Timon for your response! Nick

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the month using the `month()` function from the `lubridate` package. Thus, the following should do the job:

```
df %>%
  filter(lubridate::month(Time) %in% c(2:6))
```

Comment: That threw an error when I ran it on my example `df` where `Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. ` More importantly though, my real data has >500,000 observations so indexing by row will not work for me in this situation. I've never used `lubridate::month()` though! Some variation of this will likely work.

Comment: It worked for me with the example `df`. Are you using the `filter()` function from the `dplyr` package? I am using dplyr 1.0.4 and lubridate 1.7.9.2. Could you maybe try and create a new variable first, i.e., `mutate(Month = lubridate::month(Time)) %>% filter(Month %in% c(2:6))`? This yields the same result for me (with the additional variable). Why would indexing by row with `filter()` not work on >500k observations?